# How to reset/restart Cinnamon if the panels become invisible

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

This question is a port of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143838/how-do-i-restart-cinnamon-from-the-tty) applied to a similar but distinct issue:

### Problem:

The Cinnamon panel (my system: Linux Mint 19.1) became "invisible", that is, it still responded to mouse-clicks but became completely transparent.

### Cause:

Having plugged in an external HDMI monitor and having switched to tty1 with CTRL+ALT+F1 and back to tty7 with CTRL+ALT+F7 (where Cinnamon runs) in order to have the external monitor recognized by the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is a port of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/265977/738083) applied to a similar but distinct issue:

To restart the Cinnamon Panel

1. type <kbd>ALT+F2</kbd> to open the command box
2. and then type <kbd>r</kbd> and enter.